# Is it possible to make all-custom point marker design in highstock?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need my chart to have a pulsating last point.

I have dynamically updated chart http://jsfiddle.net/jswbouaa/

```
    chart: {
    events: {
        load: function () {

            // set up the updating of the chart each second
            var series = this.series[0];
            setInterval(function () {
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                    y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
},
```

and a CSS-animated point https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rpwqOg?editors=1100#0

Is it possible to implement this animated point into the chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See this **demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/zaeas1aw/

I created the marker using `SVGRenderer.text()`. Then I wrote function called `positionMarker` which is responsible for changing the position of the marker. I call it once after the data is set initially and after each point addition:

```
function positionMarker(series) {
  var lastPoint,
    chart = series.chart,
    lastPoint = series.points[series.points.length - 1];

  chart.pulseMarker.animate({
    x: lastPoint.plotX - chart.plotLeft - chart.spacing[0],
    y: lastPoint.plotY + chart.plotTop + chart.spacing[2] - 3
  }, true);
}

(...)

  load: function() {

    var chart = this;
    chart.pulseMarker = this.renderer.text("<span class='mgo-widget-call_pulse'></span>", 200, 200, true).add();

    // set up the updating of the chart each second
    var series = this.series[0];
    // change the position of pulse marker                  
    positionMarker(series);


    setInterval(function() {
      var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

      series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

      // change the position of pulse marker                    
      positionMarker(series);

    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to make this point animate like the chart does?

Comment: Sure, I replaced the `attr()` with `animate()`: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/zaeas1aw/ (same fiddle)